# Qual regra posso usar para ter acesso administrador ao Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, autenticação, firestore

Olá eu gostaria de saber se existe alguma regra no firebase firestore, onde apenas a conta do meu projeto possa ter acesso para modificação, isso sem ter que desenvolver um sistema de autenticação, ou seja, o simples fato de eu estar logado no google com minha conta do email já me dê permissão para tal feito...

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started?hl=pt-br

Procurei nesse documento, mas aparentemente nada que seja próximo do que eu quero.

Answer (score 1):

você pode usar:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.email == seu_email
    }
  }
}
```

no entanto eu recomendo utilizar customClaims, que são parâmetros que são gravados junto ao token de autênticacao do firebase.
para isso você precisa utilizar o firebase-admin

```
admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(uid, {admin: true}).then(() => {
  // Os parâmetros irão se propagar tokens. talvez necessite de relogar com sua conta no app.
});
```

fazendo isto agora você pode utilizar as regras de segurança para o firestore (firestore rules):

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.token.admin == true
    }
  }
}
```

agora todos os documentos só poderão ser gravados e lodos pelo administrador.
mais informações em: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#set_and_validate_custom_user_claims_via_the_admin_sdk

observação: para acessar o firebase-admin você precisará de uma conta de serviço. https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize_the_sdk